# How can I prevent pets from passing through an open window?

Tags: security, sliding-glass-door, curtain-rail

We live in a 6th floor and we have a huge sliding glass window that we like to open. The issue is that we have cats, so my concern is that if we leave the window open, one of the cats will jump out the window.

So, my question is: what can I purchase to cover the window when it's open so that we get the breeze and the cat doesn't jump through the open window?

I can't cover it with curtains (it'll stop the breeze), and I don't want to cover it with ugly shades.

The windows looks something like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if there is a groove on the outside edge of the window for a typical window screen?

Comment: Does it not have a screen? What golden utopia do you live in without mosquitoes and flies?

Comment: [Window screens aren't really used in Britain](http://www.diy.com/search?Ntt=window+screen), it's not that buggy. That would be my guess.

Comment: Get smarter cats

Comment: That's almost impossible.

Comment: Would a child be able to get out the open window?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't trust a typical bug screen to keep a pet in (or out). But Google `window pet mesh` and you can find plenty of similar looking products specifically designed to stand up to pets, such as: [Super Screen - Pet & Weather Resistant](https://www.metroscreenworks.com/super-screen-pet-weather-resistant/).

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. Live with the fact that your cat wants to be a part-time outdoor cat.

The danger of the great outdoors for pets is vastly overrated. Do make sure the cat can't reproduce though.

Option 2. Add a bug screen. They also work wonders as a cat screen as long as the cat doesn't sharpen his nails on it. You can build one yourself using a double frame of wood and sandwiching the edges of the screen between the frames. You can also route a slot on the inside of the built frame and using a strip of wood to clamp it down. Then nail the strip in place.

A diy screen door kit can also be an option provided the provided screen can cover the area you need.